# Error Updating GDAL using pip (python3) on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

Tags: python-3.x, pip, gdal, ubuntu-20.04

I have a Linux Server (Ubuntu 20.04 LTS) and I am trying to update GDAL.
All below has been used to update packages:

```
/usr/bin/python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip
/usr/bin/python3 -m pip install --upgrade wheel
/usr/bin/python3 -m pip install --upgrade setuptools
```

Then, to check GDAL version:

```
gdal2tiles.py --version
```

```
GDAL 3.0.4, released 2020/01/28
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/gdal2tiles.py", line 2915, in <module>
    main()
  File "/usr/bin/gdal2tiles.py", line 2905, in main
    input_file, output_folder, options = process_args(argv[1:])
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

I am not sure why those errors just when showing the version.

Anyhow, I use the following command to try to update GDAL and I get error about building the wheel:

```
/usr/bin/python3 -m pip install --upgrade GDAL
```

Errors:

```
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: legacy-install-failure

× Encountered error while trying to install package.
╰─> GDAL

      extensions/gdal_wrap.cpp:5573:13: warning: ‘CheckNumericDataType’ defined but not used [-Wunused-variable]
       5573 | static bool CheckNumericDataType(GDALExtendedDataTypeHS* dt)
            |             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      error: command '/usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit code 1
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: legacy-install-failure

× Encountered error while trying to install package.
╰─> GDAL
```